# How to get user's MaximunAttachmentSize value in Outlook VSTO

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

How to get user's MaximunAttachmentSize value in Outlook VSTO.

Outlook gives a warning when the user adds the file with drag and drop, but when he sends the mail, the mail does not go.

What I want to do is to show the message box if the added file size is larger than outlook MaximunAttachmentSize.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cexml.png)

When I say Upload file with Attach File I get an error like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euRnY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the `PR_MAX_SUBMIT_MESSAGE_SIZE` MAPI property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x666D0003`) from the `Store` object (`((MAPIFolder)MailItem.Parent).Store`) using `Store.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty()`.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you check the file size before attaching it using System.IO.File api?